# サポートへの問い合わせは日本語でも可能ですか？

Tags: サポート

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは、[このフォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から運営へ問い合わせができます。

この問い合わせは、日本語でも通じますか？　英語で書いた方が良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

現時点で私が知っている情報を。

1. お問い合わせフォームから送信されたお問い合わせは、おそらく StackExchange 社の Community Team (以下、SE担当者)へと通達されます。
2. 対応を行うのは、基本的にSE担当者です。
3. SE担当者から、モデレータへ、問合せ対応のヘルプを依頼されることがあります。問い合わせの全部そうなのか、一部だけなのかは、ちょっと私には分かっていません。

結論:

1. 英語に流暢ならば、英語で書いた方が伝わりやすいのは事実です。
2. 日本語でも対応されているはずです。

個人的な提案:

- 十分な信用度があるならば[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17893/)で私などモデレータを @ mentionで捕まえて、 public でない相談を開始したいんだけど、と知らせていただければ、非公開チャットを作るってそこで要件を聞くなどして、モデレータ権限でできる範囲において、対応は可能です。

Comment: 別の質問に書いた、ログインの追加の件、ヘルプの画面が分からなかったので、問合せ(日本語)を行ったのですが、質問の仕方が悪いのか、返信が無いです。その後、ログイン追加できそうな画面を見つけたのですが、上手くいかなく、こちらへの質問となっています。対応されているのでしょうか?

Comment: 昨日、ログインの件について返信がありました。　日本語の質問に対し、英語での返信。仕方が無いので、(怪しい)英語で返信しました。

Comment: ここにお願いすればMetaでの疑問はだいたい解決するんでしょうか？特にSOFのシステム的な謎について。

Comment: もう一つの質問に追記しましたが、、、、結局、英語が必要なのかと思います。 それは、日本語版としては、致命的ではないかと。